# Automatically transfer completed downloads from seedbox home

Tags: linux, rsync, bittorrent, rtorrent

I'm pondering a move to ruTorrent/rTorrent and was wondering how people have gone about automating transferring content from their seedbox to a linux based home server.
I'd like to:

1 - Download content and on completion, have it unpacked and moved to a specific folder according to the label - Eg: if the label is "Linux" have the archives unpack the contents to /Complete/Linux but still have the original files continue to seed.

2 - Once the file has been unpacked, automatically launch a script to remotely transfer the new file via scp/rsync/ftps/whatever to a remote location.

3 - Make sure the file is only transferred once and delete it from the seedbox if transferred successfully.

I know about the RSS feeds in ruTorrent and the AutoTools plugin, but have not been able to find a way to launch a script or unpack based on labels etc...
I'd also ideally like to find a way to do this without cron jobs.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!